# Error: Numbers in exponential notation should always contain an exponent (an integer number with an optional sign)

Tags: flutter

```
../../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:5:21: Error: Numbers in exponential notation should always contain an exponent (an integer number with an optional sign).
```

All of a sudden, Flutter threw this error. Anybody know why?

Comment: haha, i figured out. I accidentally added "4e" in some flutter sdk file.